# How do I solve NameError or ModuleNotFound error when importing modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to structure my code. I'm testing the modules I created but I'm consistently getting either a "NameError: class  is not defined" or a ModuleNotFound error. How do I solve this? Is there a problem in my init files and/or structuring? I'm using Python 3.x.

This is the structure of my project:

```
projectfoldername/
     __init1__.py
     module1.py
     folder1/
         __init2__.py
         module2.py
         module3.py
     folder2/
         __init3__.py
         module4.py
test.py
```

I've tried different ways to structure the init files. I've also tried to use the sys.path but deemed it as a bad practice. I've also tried importing the project through: import projectfoldername, given that I have the init files available in each package

For more details, here's the current way I structured each init.

**__init1__**.py

```
from .module1 import ClassA
import folder1
import folder2
```

**__init2__**.py

```
from .module2 import ClassB
from .module3 import ClassC
```

**__init3__**.py

```
from .module4 import ClassD
```

**Additional Info**

module2.py

```
from ..module1.py import ClassA
class B(ClassA)
```

module3.py

```
from .module2.py import ClassB
class C(ClassB)
```

module4.py

```
from ..module1.py import ClassA
class D(ClassA)
```

Comment: Your various `__init1__.py` and `__init2__.py` should definitely not have those numbers in their names.  Rename all of them to just `__init__.py`

Comment: If you have classes that refer to one another, you can only put them in separate modules if the references are hierarchical. If A refers to B and B refers to A then put them both in the same module. *One class per module* is normal in compiled languages, but is difficult to make work in dynamic languages, and so much trouble you probably shouldn't bother.

Comment: @Hoog - I'm sorry, I forgot to tell that the numbers for each init.py are just for explicit specification's sake.

Comment: @BoarGules - I think that might be the problem. I've recently come upon circular imports in Python which hinders the importing process. I think it was triggered by the classes inheriting one another so I might've to rethink the structure of the project and the modules itself.